# How to compare 'year to fraction' and 'year to day' DATETIME fields

Tags: sql, datetime

I am trying to write a select where part of my criteria is comparing two DATETIME fields (from two different tables). One is Year to Fraction, where the other is Year to Day. Is there a way to write the expression so that the year to fraction value gets shortened to year to day? I'm not looking to shorten the field for the output, rather I need it in the logic itself to compare the fields as equals.

Here is a watered down look at what I am trying to get to:

```
SELECT BLAH
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B = T2.B
                                AND T1.FIELD1 = 100
                                AND T1.TIMESTAMP = T2.WORDERDATE
```

`T1.TIMESTAMP` is year to fraction, `T2.WORDERDATE` is year to day

Any assistance, in very plain English if possible, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what is the notion of "year to fraction" and "year to date"? What qualifies a date as being one of those?

Answer (score 0):

Can you cast them and then compare?

```
SELECT BLAH
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B = T2.B
                            AND T1.FIELD1 = 100
                            AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST(T1.TIMESTAMP AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(T2.WORDERDA AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfect for what I was needing to acomplish. I appreciate your help. I tried to mark the answer as useful, but since I am so new to the site I don't have enough repuation to do so. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Beemer: I have a data dictionary that tells me specifically that the fields are year to day or year to fraction, I can visually see the field length in the database as well. The year to day field is only ten positions long, where the year to fraction is much longer.

OMG Ponies: The database is actually an HP Tandem database, but the data has been replicated onto an Oracle server, where I am targeting my information from.

jon3laze: I am not familar with CAST, FLOOR or FLOAT, but thank you for your reply. I will try out your answer tomorrow to see if I can make it work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something similar. At least on a Tandem (or HP NonStop), the following suffices:

```
SELECT BLAH
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B = T2.B
                                AND T1.FIELD1 = 100
                                AND T1.TIMESTAMP YEAR TO DAY = T2.WORDERDATE YEAR TO DAY
```

This will cast both Timestamps to "YEAR TO DAY", i.e. the format "YYYY-MM-DD".